# Query results using odbc in python

Tags: python, sql, if-statement, odbc, pyodbc

```
import pyodbc as odbc

Driver = 'SQL Server'
server_name = ''
database_name = ''

conn = odbc.connect(f"""
    Driver={{{Driver}}};
    Server={server_name};
    Database={database_name};
    UID=;
    PWD=;
                      """)


def sku_search():

    SKU_check = '''SELECT [ITEMSKU] FROM
    [StilettoXT].[dbo].[PRODDETAIL] WHERE
    ITEMSKU = (?)'''
    SKU_code = input('Please enter the SKU code: ')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(SKU_check, SKU_code)
    if cursor.fetchall() == []:
        print('Not Found')
    elif cursor.fetchall() != []:
        print('Found')


sku_search()

conn.close()
```

I'm having real difficulty trying to get the following code to work, specially the 'elif' part of the my if statement. If you run the script with an invalid SKU code that doesn't exists in that database, you get the print statement. If you run with a valid SKU code, nothing gets returned even though the cursor.fetchall() is not an empty list. If you swap the if and elif arguments round, you will only get a result for the 'if' part of the function. I can't understand why the 'elif' part returns nothing. If you query an invalid sku code, SQL will return a blank value. I've tried to reference this as None as well but the same issue.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Usually there should be `cursor.rowcount`, which returns the number of 'selected' rows.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer - Many ODBC drivers return -1 as the `.rowcount` of a SELECT query because the actual number of rows returned might not be known until they are actually  retrieved from the server.

Comment: You're calling fetchall() twice without an execute() before the second (your select only returns one result set)... You should probably store the result in a variable..?

Comment: You are calling `.fetchall()` twice, and the second time it may return an empty result set regardless of what the first `.fetchall()` returned. Call `.fetchall()` once as `results = cursor.fetchall()` and then test the value of `results` to decide what to do.

Comment: Thanks very much, it now works using cursor.rowcount and setting it to: 'code'
if cursor.rowcount == -1:
        print('Found')
elif cursor.rowcount == 0:
        print('Not Found')
'code'
With regards to setting the fetchall() as a variable, I'd tried that but it didn't work. For whatever reason, the 'elif' statement would never produce a result but now using cursor.rowcount, it all works